# Accidentally started emacs --daemon, and couldn't kill it!

Tags: emacsclient, emacs-daemon

I was testing `emacs --daemon` functionality, and called two daemons alive. I wanted to kill them, with

```
$ pgrep emacs
275760
275857
$ pkill emacs
$ pgrep emacs
276788
276847
# It's alive again!
# Lemme kill them with emacsclient --eval
$ emacsclient -e "(kill-emacs)"
$ pgrep emacs
277339
277340
```

Are they zombies? I'm sure shutting down my laptop will really kill them.. but just to boost my understanding, what was going on here? How to kill emacs daemons properly (and gracefully?).

Comment: Could it be that you are running Emacs as a systemd service?  Then it may happen that it is re-started. See, e.g., https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486417/systemd-restart-service-automatically-only-after-crash

Comment: I am not aware of that.. I eventually kill it by killing it fast multiple times! And it eventually dies without coming up again. It really felt like I was killing a zombie.